# Finding the matrix of a rotation.

Tags: matrices, rotations

I have to find the corresponding matrix for the following rotation:

$R_ \frac{π}{4}$ (1,1)

My general matrix formula is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&h\\ 0&1&k\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}cosα&-sinα&0\\ sinα&cosα&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-h\\ 0&1&-k\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} $$

I have said that $h$=1 and $k$=1 therefore my matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\ 0&1&1\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}cosα&-sinα&0\\ sinα&cosα&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-1\\ 0&1&-1\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}(1)(1)+(0)(0)+(1)(0) & (1)(0)+(0)(1)+(1)(0) & (1)(-1)+(0)(-1)+(1)(1)\\(0)(1)+(1)(0)+(0)(0) & (0)(0)+(1)(1)+(1)(0) & (0)(-1)+(1)(-1)+(1)(1) \\ (0)(1)+(0)(0)+(1)(0) & (0)(0)+(0)(1)+(1)(0) & (0)(-1)+(0)(-1)+(1)(1) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}cosα&-sinα&0\\ sinα&cosα&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}cosα&-sinα&0\\ sinα&cosα&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}
(1)(cosα)+(0)(sinα)+(0)(0) & (1)(-sinα)+(0)(cosα)+(0)(0) & (1)(0)+(0)(0)+(0)(1)\\
(0)(cosα)+(1)(sinα)+(0)(0) & (0)(-sinα)+(1)(cosα)+(0)(0) & (0)(-1)+(1)(-1)+(0)(1)\\
(0)(cosα)+(0)(sinα)+(1)(0) & (0)(-sinα)+(0)(cosα)+(1)(0) & (0)(-1)+(0)(-1)+(1)(1) \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix} cosα&-sinα& 0\\sinα&cosα&-1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Does this matrix look right? My notes has something different for the third column.

Comment: Apologies for any poor editing on the question.

Comment: What does $R_{\frac{\pi}{4}}(1,1)$ mean?

Comment: @okarin it is a rotation of π4 about the point (1,1). I would believe that the rotation is in 2D.

Comment: Is this a rotation in 2d or 3d?

Comment: It would be a rotation in 2d

Comment: Rotation about a point which is not the origin is not a linear transformation (as it doesn't preserve the origin) and so it can't be described by a matrix (on its own anyway).

Comment: @DanielRust does this mean that it is a trick question?

Comment: It means you need to ask yourself what this matrix is supposed to do and also what the notation $R_{\theta}(a,b)$ means. Basically, read your notes. There's not enough context for us to be able to help you at the moment.

Comment: Ok with a bit of reading it looks like affine tranformations can be handled in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by using $3\times 3$ matrices and concatenating any vector which they are acting on by a single $1$ as the third coordinate. In this setting your matrices make sense, but you've not done the matrix multiplication correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have correctly set up your three matrices for rigid motions in the (coordinatized) Euclidean plane. We can write them $ABA^{-1}$. Then you made your first mistake, it would seem, by multiplying the outer two to each other, to get the correct answer (given your erroneous setup) for $AA^{-1}B$ That you did this right can be seen in the fact that the lefthand matrix after the second equals sign is the identity matrix. Then you seem to have made a mistake in multiplying the identity matrix times your rotation matrix $B$.

In any event, you made a serious mistake in multiplying the two outer matrices together.

Comment: I didn't think that it would matter what order I multiplied the matrices together as matrix multiplication is associative? I just tried it your way and got the same answer as in my notes. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Yeah, it’s associative, but not commutative! This is a *real* important fact about matrices.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks very much for clearing everything up. You are a great help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $R_{\theta}(a,b)\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be the affine transformation which rotates points by an angle $\theta$ anti-clockwise about the point $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. This can be described by a matrix $M\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ where $M(x,y,1)^T=(R_{\theta}(a,b)(x,y),1)^T$. In this case the matrix is given by the product of the translation matrix which maps $(a,b)$ to the origin, then the rotation in the $(x-y)$-plane by the corresponding angle and then the translation which maps the origin to $(a,b)$. All together this is the product of matrices given in your question (but with $\theta$ replacing $\alpha$ and $(a,b)=(1,1)$).

Your problem was that you didn't multiply the matrices correctly. You should get a matrix of the form $$M=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&f(\theta,a,b)\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta&g(\theta,a,b)\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Where I will leave you to find $f$ and $g$. You should also then substitute the relevant values in for $\theta,a$ and $b$.